# How to get which button is clicked in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have created a common action for an array of my button. I just want to get the which button is tapped.

I have array of buttons like `let buttons = [UIButton(), UIButton(), UIButton(),UIButton()]`.

```
let observable = Observable.of(buttons[0].rx.tap, buttons[1].rx.tap, buttons[2].rx.tap, buttons[3].rx.tap).merge()
    observable.subscribe(onNext: {
      print("I want to find which button is tapped.")
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is to not merge the buttons in the first place. If you want to do four different things, then have four different observables. If they are all doing the same thing, just with different data then simply:

```
let taps = buttons.enumerated().map { ($0.0, $0.1.rx.tap) }
let toInts = taps.map { index, obs in obs.map { index } }
let mergedTaps = Observable.merge(toInts)
```

On review, I really like an answer by @Sooraj_snr that has been deleted. Use the buttons' tags instead of their position in the array. It's much more robust.

```
let tags = buttons
    .map { ($0.rx.tap, $0.tag) }
    .map { obs, tag in obs.map { tag } }
let values = Observable.merge(tags)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just map the tap events to some custom IDs -

```swift
let observable = Observable.merge(
  buttons[0].rx.tap.map { 0 },
  buttons[1].rx.tap.map { 1 },
  // etc.
)

observable.subscribe(onNext: { id in
  print("\(id) button is tapped.")
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using merge(). You can't know which on is being tapped.

If you want multiple buttons but one action you are doing the right thing.

```
let observable = Observable.of(buttons[0].rx.tap, buttons[1].rx.tap, 
    buttons[2].rx.tap, buttons[3].rx.tap).merge()
    observable.subscribe(onNext: {
    print("I want to find which button is tapped.")
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

If the action is different then:
**Example**
Let's say I have a UIView and 4 buttons. In button tap, you change the background of the view. Different color per button. So same function but different color.

```
Observable.of(UIButton().rx.tap.map { _ in UIColor.red }).merge().subscribe(onNext: { color in
       UIView().backgroundColor = color
   })
```

Comment: Please write this as comment, not as an answer.

Comment: @tspentzas, Can you please suggest another way instead of using merge().

Comment: This is a great answer but the way you have it setup requires a whole lot of boilerplate. Better would be to have an array of colors along with the array of buttons, `zip` them and then combine them like I did in my answer. The result would be shorter code that's easer to understand and change (adding and removing buttons would be much less painful.) I'm upvoting your answer anyway, but I would love to see you upgrade it by incorporating some of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here we give the button tag.

```
buttons.enumerated().forEach { (index, button) in
  button.tag = index
}
```

Here we got the which button we have selected.

```
for button in buttons {
  button.rx.tap.subscribe { [weak self] event in
    print("Selected Button :- \(button.tag)")
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```